# Twitter search API, how to filter by @username?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API atom format

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=some_hashtag
```

but it's return me tweets with hashtag "some_hashtag" from all people. i'm looking for some filter to search all tweets with hashtag "some_hashtag" only from one user, for example @this_one.

I did not find this parameter on the "[twitter get search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)" documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to give an extra parameter to the `q`: `from:`.

For example, retreiving tweets for hashtag `some_hashtag` by `@VictimCommunity`:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=some_hashtag%20from:VictimCommunity
```

It's described in the [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) but was a bit hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter does not allow you to search for keywords for a particular set of users.

As you are only "searching" one user's tweets, I would suggest that you just read the users timeline with `include_entities` and filter the results with with PHP your end:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline?screen_name=this_one&include_entities=1
```

Now use PHP to read through...

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) 
{
    if (in_array('hashtag', $tweet->entities->hashtags))
    {
        // go...
    }
}
```

Edit: Whilst this still valid, I suggest looking at this [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179046/twitter-search-api-how-to-filter-by-username#answer-12179316).

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two pages:

[Twitter Search Api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)

[Twitter Search Api Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)